# Convert the code to Java 8 approach with function references etc

Tags: java, java-8

I have a class as follows:

```
public class MyClass {  
  interface MyBuilder {  
      List<MyObject> initObjects(String quantifier);  
  }  

  private static class Builder1 implements MyBuilder {  
      @Override  
      List<MyObject> initObjects(String quantifier) {  
        // code omitted for clarity

      }  
  }  

  private static class Builder2 implements MyBuilder {  
      @Override  
      List<MyObject> initObjects(String quantifier) {  
        // code omitted for clarity

      }  
  }  

  private static HashMap<String, MyBuilder> builders = ….;  
  static {  
     builders.put("type1", new Builder1());  
     builders.put("type2", new Builder2());  
  }  
  //etc
```

Is there a way to convert this code to function references via Java8 and somehow make it “shorter”?
I would like to practice some of the Java8 idioms with function references etc

Comment: You might find this enlightening https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html

Comment: Yes, as these appear to implement a SAM interface, you can replace them with lambdas.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: What is a SAM interface?

Comment: @Jim Single Abstract Method, your interface qualifies as such

Answer (score 4):

Because `MyBuilder` is a Functional Interface (an interface with a single method), you can inline the implementations of `Builder1` and `Builder2`:

```
static {  
  builders.put("type1", quantifier -> /*code here*/);  
  builders.put("type2", quantifier -> /*code here*/);  
}
```

Additionally, your `MyBuilder` interface is equivalent to `java.util.function.Function<String, List<MyObject>>`:

```
private static HashMap<String, Function<String, List<MyObject>> builders = ….;
```

Comment: But this will make the code implementation be inline with the hashmap declaration. I think that will make the code less readable. I was asking about java 8 in case I could make the code shorter. But +1 for the Function

Comment: You could always assign the lambdas to static variables and then build the map using those. Ultimately, it depends on how long the code is; long lambdas are bad for your mental health.

Comment: Seems that I can't use `java.util.Function` in Android Studio

Comment: I'm not familiar with Android Studio but can you elaborate why not?

Comment: I was hoping you would elaborate actually on this. From what I understand it depends on the target API of the app

Comment: Just noticed it's actually `java.util.function.Function`. The class should be in version 8 of the JDK and it shows in the docs : https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/function/Function.html

Comment: Yes but this depends on the target API if java 8 is used (API>24)

Answer (score 2):

Well I don't really like this, especially if you have lots of implementations, but you could keep everything inside the interface:

```
interface MyBuilder {
    public List<MyObject> initObjects(String quantifier);

    default List<MyObject> initObjectsType1() {
        return initObjects("type1");
    }

    default List<MyObject> initObjectsType2() {
        return initObjects("type2");
    }
}
```